# Why is jquery mobile not working for Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

The day has come that I finally register here and have to ask my question because I am already so desperate.

I am starting a new Phonegap project and I want/need to use jquery mobile. I want to use a flipswitch (like shown here: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/flipswitch/). My problem is that neither this flipswitch nor other jquery mobile specific objects like buttons are displayed correctly. The flipswitch code for example only shows a normal checkbox.

The includes (js and stylesheet) for jquery mobile should be correct (also the path).

I don't think that it has something to do with Phonegap. Even if I cut out all the Phonegap specific code and open the remaining code in a browser (tried Firefox and Chrome) only a checkbox gets displayed and no flipswitch. Or am I doing something else completely wrong?

I use the following code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
    <script src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <title>Home Automatization</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="app">
      <form>
        <label for="flip-checkbox-1">Flip toggle switch checkbox:</label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="flip-checkbox-1" id="flip-checkbox-1">
      </form>
      <button class="ui-btn ui-corner-all">Button</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If anyone could help me I would appreciate it very very much and thank you a thousand times.

Comment: You must have the path for the js and/or css files wrong. Do you have `jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css` in the same level as your index.html?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have it in a folder called "jquery". This folder is situated on the same level as the index.html. That's exactly what irritates me. The referrencing should work as far as I see it.

Comment: @Mati Tucci I just realised that I had the wrong path for jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css but correcting that did not solve my problem.

Comment: Have you tryed adding type="text/JavaScript"?

Comment: I just did all of this locally and it worked. You must have wrong the path/s. Put the 3 files (`jquery.js`, `jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js` and `jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css`) in the same level as your `index.html`. And update the references in the `<head>`. Also, are you sure that the jQuery file is called only `jquery.js` and not something like `jquery-2.2.0.js`?

Comment: Check your browser console for errors. I've tested your markup and it should work without issue provided the paths are correct. If you still can't see the problem, use the CDN snippet at https://jquerymobile.com/download/ (see 'Copy-and-Paste snippet for jQuery CDN hosted files') as a temporary replacement for your JavaScript and CSS paths and you should find it'll work. I'll post an answer as an example.

Comment: Thank you too @MatiTucci for your help. That problem nearly robbed my sleep yesterday. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example I've commented out your index.css file and replaced the other JavaScript and CSS paths with the CDN snippet from https://jquerymobile.com/download/ - you should find this works correctly:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" /> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <title>Home Automatization</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="app">
      <form>
        <label for="flip-checkbox-1">Flip toggle switch checkbox:</label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="flip-checkbox-1" id="flip-checkbox-1">
      </form>
      <button class="ui-btn ui-corner-all">Button</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If this works, put your index.css file back in and test again. Add in your original paths one by one and test - be sure to check your browser console for errors.

Comment: Thank you very very much, you made my day.
It works now flawlessly in Firefox but in Chrome the page is infintitely loading. Do you have any idea what could be the reason?
It seems that I indeed messed up something with the scripts and css files. May I ask why you imported **jquery-1.11.1.min.js** ? I downloaded jquery mobile and it only contained the .js files **jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js**  and **jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js**. Those have been (as it seems) not enough.

Comment: Glad it helped. jQuery Mobile needs the core jQuery library in order to work. I guess the jQM team either can't distribute it or don't want to have the maintenance overhead of doing so. Re: Chrome I think you'll have issues if you launch the HTML page by opening it as a file:// rather than running it on a web server.

Comment: All of what you have written is correct. It works with Chrome when I run it on a local Apache server.